# Data not importing completely by using SOLR 6

Tags: solr, solr6

I am using Solr 6

I am not getting any error from SOLR logs .. perhaps I am not getting complete data when fires query from SOLR UI.
I am getting only [SOLR response][1]

solrconfig.xml

```
    <requestHandler name="/dataimport" 
               class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
      <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">solr-data-config.xml</str>
      </lst>
    </requestHandler>
```

This is my configuration file solr-data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxxxx_schema" user="root" password="xxxxxx" />
    <document>
        <entity name="implas" query="select 
UID,
IMP_DEVICE_ID,
IMP_DEVICE_ISSUE_AGY,
IMP_BRAND_NAME,
IMP_COMPANY_NAME,
IMP_VERSION_MDL_NUM,
IMP_MRI_SAFETY_STATUS,
IMP_GMDN_TERMS,
IMP_LABEL_CONT_NRL,
IMP_CREATED_USER,
IMP_CREATED_TS,
IMP_UPDATED_USER,
IMP_UPDATED_TS from xxxxxxx_master">
            <field column="UID" name="id" />
            <field column="imp_device_id" name="impdevice" />
            <field column="imp_device_issue_agy" name="impissue" />
            <field column="imp_brand_name" name="impbrand" />
            <field column="IMP_COMPANY_NAME" name="impcompany" />
            <field column="IMP_VERSION_MDL_NUM" name="impversion" />
            <field column="IMP_MRI_SAFETY_STATUS" name="impmri" />
            <field column="IMP_GMDN_TERMS" name="impgdn" />
            <field column="IMP_LABEL_CONT_NRL" name="implable" />
            <field column="IMP_CREATED_USER" name="impcreated" />
            <field column="IMP_CREATED_TS" name="impts" />
            <field column="IMP_UPDATED_USER" name="impupdated" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>



Response :

{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "indent":"on",
      "wt":"json",
      "_":"1495186229665"}},
  "response":{"numFound":12000,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"1",
        "_version_":1567804808791851008},
      {
        "id":"2",
        "_version_":1567804808792899584},
      {
        "id":"3",
        "_version_":1567804808793948160},
      {
        "id":"4",
        "_version_":1567804808793948161},
      {
        "id":"5",
        "_version_":1567804808794996736},
      {
        "id":"6",
        "_version_":1567804808794996737},
      {
        "id":"7",
        "_version_":1567804808794996738},
      {
        "id":"8",
        "_version_":1567804808796045312},
      {
        "id":"9",
        "_version_":1567804808796045313},
```

Comment: The response image is not uploaded it seems. did you commit documents after dataImport?

Comment: Why the ibm-midrange tag on this? Looks like you are using MySQL rather than DB2.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy - Or maybe that's just it. Maybe OP is trying to connect to DB2 on a midrange, but is using the MySQL driver? I don't know what "[SOLR response][1]" means, so it's hard to tell how far OP got.

Comment: MySql or DB2 , it just a database , i am connecting to but My SOLR response is not getting even my import is successful .

Comment: @squid 
I have updated response Sir please verify.

Comment: MySQL or DB2, it matters because the drivers are different. The Syntax is slightly different in some cases. I think this is either a problem with your database driver, or a problem with SOLR, but I am not convinced that it is an issue with `IBM i`.

Comment: Driver conf is good I am using jt400 driver, I can able to ping the DB server